# iPad Simulator not receiving touch events outside of iPhone's 320x480 frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, touchesbegan

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"test x:%f",gestureStartPoint.x);
    NSLog(@"test y:%f",gestureStartPoint.y);
    etc..
```

Srangely, I'm not receiving any log statements if I click outside a 320x480 frame (starting from upper-left corner). Elsewhere in touchesBegan I call other methods passing in the touch and these weren't responding, so put these NSLogs in.

What do I have to do to receive touch events from the full 1024x768 view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a bug in the "Upgrade Current Target for iPad" task.

I fixed this issue by creating a new "Window XIB" with iPad as the product, then replacing the Window object in MainWindow-iPad.xib with the Window object in the new XIB. (Be sure to update the "window" outlet of your app delegate.)

Comment: Thanks. Making a new project did it for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Is your UIView actually the full size of the window?

Comment: This is probably the answer to the problem, views get the touches Began only in their frame, not in all the superview.

Comment: Thanks, this was originally an iPhone/iPod project that I set the target family to iPad. I resized the View, that didn't work.. so I erased & set a new view to  784 x 1024, by frame upper left corner, expanding in all directions (all red arrows selected). Still same behavior.. I'll try making a new iPad app then copying the code over (the old project was from pre-Xcode 4).